# Need JS help- collapsing a toggled down element when another is selected

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Need help with the "our team" section halfway down this page: http://dev.doubleaevents.com/

When you click an image it opens to reveal more information. I'd like to be able to click another image and have the previously opened image collapse, so that a user can't open more than one image at a time.

Would also like to know if making them slide out to the right (instead of down) would be a simple fix?

I'm a js novice so any explanations are appreciated. Here's the js file for quick reference: http://dev.doubleaevents.com/wp-content/plugins/portfolio-gallery/assets/js/view-toggle-up-down.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
jQuery('.portelement').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('large')){
        jQuery(this).removeClass('large');
        jQuery(this).animate({
            height:240
        },300);
     }
});
```

before:

```
jQuery(this).parents('.portelement').addClass('large');
```

In your javascript code.

When you click an item you basically want to search for elements that are already open. Then from there remove the 'large' class name and close that element. From there you continue on to opening the selected element. Thats what this code does.

As far as your other question, it shouldn't be too difficult, just mess around with the animate method and css. But maybe look into the isotope documentation. There may be an option for that.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much @LegenJerry, you're a life saver!